# groff to PS Conversion

Tags: cygwin, postscript, roff

I am very new to **`UNIX`**, learning **`groff`** with the help of **`cygwin`** on **`Windows XP SP3`**.

I have downloaded **`groff-binaries`** from [***here***](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/groff.htm), but using [**`cygwin`**](http://www.cygwin.com/), I could not able to re-produce **`ps`** files.

I have used following command in **`cygwin`**:

```
$ groff grnexmpl.me > grnexmpl.ps
```

But, in generated `grnexmpl.ps` file, all special formatting are gone. When I look inside the `grnexmpl.ps.gz` archive(comes with the binaries) and the `grnexmpl.ps` looks beautiful.  It would be a great help if somebody assist me to understand what is going here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `groff` which macros you want to use. In this case, you want

```
groff -ge -me -mwww grnexmpl.me > out.ps
```

If you want to see the picture of the circuit diagram, you'll also need `grnexample.g` present in the directory.

I found this by running [grog](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?grog%281%29) to guess the macros, and then added the `www` macro, since I could see there was HTML in the source document.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your prompt reply. The issue is solved now. The ``command`` works like charm. But, as you refers to ``grog``, I just unable to run that. I could see the file to be present at `/usr/bin/grog` and I also have `strawberry perl` installed in my mc. But running command `grog -Tdvi grnexmpl.me` cygwin trows error `«Can't open perl script "grog": No such file or directory»`. Could you please tell me, why?

Comment: I guess using `cygwin build perl` would be the solution to run `perl scripts` from `cygwin`!

Comment: @Cylian - Sorry, I don't use Cygwin. But it may be a path issue with the wrong Perl install: [What is the reason for this “Can't open perl script : No such file or directory?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5865867/143804)